# Endomorphism of Chow group induced by a birational map

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, intersection-theory, algebraic-cycles

Let $\phi:X\dashrightarrow Y$ be a birational map between smooth projective $k$-varieties ($k=\bar k$) and $\Gamma$ be the closure of the graph of $\phi$. In Fulton's intersection theory example 16.1.11, it is said that $^t\Gamma\circ\Gamma$ is the sum of the identity correspondence and correspondences whose projections are contained in proper subvarieties of $Y$ but I cannot see why it is (formally) true.

Comment: We see that the restriction of $^t\Gamma\circ \Gamma$ to $U\times U$ (where $U$ is an open subset on which $\phi$ is a morphism) at like $\phi_*\phi^*$ on the Chow ring of $X$ but a priori the homomorphism from correspondence to endomorphism of Chow ring is not injective (isn't it?)

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/a/241907/82179

Answer (score 1):

Let $U $ be the largest open subset of $X$ where $\phi$ is defined. Let $d=dim X$. Then the sequence $$CH_d(X\times X-U\times U)\to CH_d(X\times X)\to  CH_d(U\times U)\to 0$$ is exact. Now consider the cycle $\alpha:=\Gamma^t\circ\Gamma-\Delta$ on $X\times X$. Here $\Delta$ is the diagonal. Its restriction on $U\times U$ is 0. Hence $\alpha$ is supported on the complement $X\times X-U\times U$. Thus we get the required assertion.